# Only first object has normals in OBJ

Tags: c++, opengl, blender, wavefront

I've been making a .obj file loader class. At one point I was trying to load obj-file containing multiple objects, but I couldn't get it to work.

Now I realised that when you export multiple objects from Blender into obj-file, only the first object has normals. Is there a way to make it give all the objects normals or do I have to start computing them myself?

Here's two cubes in a single obj-file. You can see that only the first one has "vn . . ." lines.

```
# Blender v2.67 (sub 1) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib font.mtl
o Cube.004_Cube.005
v 3.100306 -2.415467 -4.025629
v 3.100306 -2.415467 -2.978886
v 2.053563 -2.415467 -2.978886
v 2.053564 -2.415467 -4.025629
v 3.100306 -1.368724 -4.025628
v 3.100305 -1.368724 -2.978886
v 2.053563 -1.368724 -2.978886
v 2.053564 -1.368724 -4.025629
vt 0.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 0.000000
vt 0.000000 1.000000
vt 1.000000 1.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn -0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 1.000000 -0.000000 0.000000
vn -0.000000 -0.000000 1.000000
vn -1.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
vn 1.000000 0.000000 0.000001
usemtl Material1
s off
f 1/1/1 2/2/1 4/3/1
f 5/1/2 8/2/2 6/3/2
f 1/1/3 5/2/3 2/3/3
f 2/1/4 6/2/4 3/3/4
f 3/1/5 7/2/5 4/3/5
f 5/1/6 1/2/6 8/3/6
f 2/2/1 3/4/1 4/3/1
f 8/2/2 7/4/2 6/3/2
f 5/2/7 6/4/7 2/3/7
f 6/2/4 7/4/4 3/3/4
f 7/2/5 8/4/5 4/3/5
f 1/2/6 4/4/6 8/3/6
o Cube.003_Cube.004
v 2.891954 -3.616562 -2.073456
v 2.891954 -3.616562 -1.026714
v 1.845212 -3.616562 -1.026714
v 1.845212 -3.616562 -2.073456
v 2.891954 -2.569820 -2.073456
v 2.891954 -2.569820 -1.026713
v 1.845212 -2.569820 -1.026714
v 1.845212 -2.569820 -2.073456
vt 0.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 0.000000
vt 0.000000 1.000000
vt 1.000000 1.000000
usemtl Material2
s off
f 9/5/1 10/6/1 12/7/1
f 13/5/2 16/6/2 14/7/2
f 9/5/3 13/6/3 10/7/3
f 10/5/4 14/6/4 11/7/4
f 11/5/5 15/6/5 12/7/5
f 13/5/6 9/6/6 16/7/6
f 10/6/1 11/8/1 12/7/1
f 16/6/2 15/8/2 14/7/2
f 13/6/3 14/8/3 10/7/3
f 14/6/4 15/8/4 11/7/4
f 15/6/5 16/8/5 12/7/5
f 9/6/6 12/8/6 16/7/6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both have normals, the second cube just references the same normals as the first one.

You have to realize that the numbering of `v`, `vt` and `vn` elements continues throughout the file, so

```
o Cube.004_Cube.005
v 3.100306 -2.415467 -4.025629  #v1
v 3.100306 -2.415467 -2.978886  #v2
v 2.053563 -2.415467 -2.978886  #v3
v 2.053564 -2.415467 -4.025629  #v4
vt 0.000000 0.000000            #vt1
vt 1.000000 0.000000            #vt2
vt 0.000000 1.000000            #vt3
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000  #vn1
usemtl Material1
s off
f 1/1/1 2/2/1 4/3/1

o Cube.003_Cube.004
v 2.891954 -3.616562 -2.073456 #v5
v 2.891954 -3.616562 -1.026714 #v6
v 1.845212 -3.616562 -1.026714 #v7
v 1.845212 -3.616562 -2.073456 #v8
vt 0.000000 0.000000           #vt4
vt 1.000000 0.000000           #vt5
vt 0.000000 1.000000           #vt6
usemtl Material2
s off
f 5/4/1 6/5/1 8/6/1
```

is exactly the same as

```
v 3.100306 -2.415467 -4.025629  #v1
v 3.100306 -2.415467 -2.978886  #v2
v 2.053563 -2.415467 -2.978886  #v3
v 2.053564 -2.415467 -4.025629  #v4
v 2.891954 -3.616562 -2.073456  #v5
v 2.891954 -3.616562 -1.026714  #v6
v 1.845212 -3.616562 -1.026714  #v7
v 1.845212 -3.616562 -2.073456  #v8
vt 0.000000 0.000000            #vt1
vt 1.000000 0.000000            #vt2
vt 0.000000 1.000000            #vt3
vt 0.000000 0.000000            #vt4
vt 1.000000 0.000000            #vt5
vt 0.000000 1.000000            #vt6
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000  #vn1

o Cube.004_Cube.005
usemtl Material1
s off
f 1/1/1 2/2/1 4/3/1

o Cube.003_Cube.004
usemtl Material2
s off
f 5/4/1 6/5/1 8/6/1
```

The only rule is that you define the `v`, `vt` or `vn` before you use its index in a `f`. So if your parser has problems with this, change your parser to read it correctly.